# Using Python, how would I fit a logistic (or similar s-shaped function) to 3 points?

Tags: python

Let's say I have 3 (x, y) coordinates: `(xb, yb)`, `(xm, ym)`, and `(xt, yt)`. For simplicity, the `b`, `m` and `t` notations correspond to "bottom", "middle" and "top" (i.e. `(0, 0)`, `(0.5, 0.5)` and `(1, 1)`).

I've seen many similar SO posts using the logistic function to perform a basic "line of best fit" operation, but I need my logistic function to fit these points *exactly*. I would also prefer to not use a 3rd party library (like `scipy` or `scikit-learn`) given this is the only use case I have for these libraries. `numpy` is an exception as I use it quite liberally in my program.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, what you have is a basic question in algebra; Python is simply your implementation language.  You have three points, so you need an appropriate function with three parameters.

For a polynomial, you would need a quadratic equation, `ax^2 + bx + c`.

For a simple exponential, you would need something like `a * e^bx + c`

You have to choose your equation form; then simply solve it on each of your three points: you have three equations in three variables.  You should be able to do this by hand (since you don't want a canned program to do that for you).

In particular, the logistic function is

```
y = L / (1 + e^(-k*(x-x0)))
```

Your three parameters are L, k, and x0.  Again, plug in each point in turn, to give you three equations in three variables.  Solve for L, k, and x0.